# An application of Holder's inequality to show one norm is smaller than another

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $p(s) = r(s) + m-1$ where $r:[0,T) \to [q,\infty)$ where $q \geq 2$ and $m > 1$ is fixed.

Let $\text{Vol}(\Omega) = 1$.

Then can we show that $$\lVert u \rVert_{L^{r(s)}(\Omega)} \leq \lVert u \rVert_{L^{p(s)}(\Omega)}?$$
I know I need to use Holder's inequality but I cannot do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can forget $p(s)$, $r(s)$ and the rest and simply try to show that, for every $a\lt b$, $$\|u\|_a\leqslant\|u\|_b.$$
To wit, considering $v=|u|^a$ and $p=b/a\gt1$, note that Hölder inequality yields
$$
\int |u|^a=\int v\leqslant\left(\int v^p\right)^{1/p}=\left(\int |u|^b\right)^{a/b},
$$
that is,
$$
\left(\int |u|^a\right)^{1/a}\leqslant\left(\int |u|^b\right)^{1/b},
$$

Comment: thanks... so this inequality which is surprising is only true if the volume is 1.

Comment: Yes--as shown by elementary examples.

Comment: sorry where did you use convexity here? right at the end?

Comment: I did not, actually (but H inequality is based on it).